# iPhone ad hoc distribution without getting user details in advance

Tags: iphone, testing, adhoc

Is there anyway I can ad hoc distribute my app without asking for information about the beta-testers device?

In other words, I want to distribute my app to some friends for testing. Can I do this without requesting info from them first?

If this is not possible, exactly **what info do I need to get from them before I am able to set up an ad hoc version for them?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com).  It will allow you to invite users and will add them on-the-fly.  It's a really great tool for managing ad-hoc and beta tests for iOS.

If you do it on your own, the only info you really need is the UDID of their device.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I've come across this problem with using it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614576/build-and-archive-for-testflight-produces-big-question-mark

Comment: I've never had a problem.  I build my ipa's manually (I use MonoTouch) so that might be part of it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.

All you need is the UDID from each tester. You could suggest they use an app [like this](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/udid-tool/id377602501?mt=8) to send you their UDID to make things simple for them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need their device UUID and device name. That way you can add them to the provisioning profile so the app will run on their device, and this also allows apple to limit distribution to those on your list (max 100 devices). You then need to build the app with this provisioning profile, get your beta testers to install the provisioning profile on their device, and then finally install the app.

You could ask your users to download the excellent ad hoc helper from the app store which let's them send an email with all the info automatically generated.