# Build and Archive for TestFlight produces big question mark

Tags: iphone, adhoc, beta

I'm using TestFlight to get beta users to test my iPhone app. I've never done this before and so I'm a bit concerned with the process.

I've been following [these steps to create my .ipa](http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-3), but after step 3 I see lots of question marks in the organiser window (next to the name of my app to be specific). Should I be concerned. It seemed as if everything else worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your bundle display name set in the project info.plist file? Check that all values in info.plist are set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this one?

[image]

Nothing to worry, this happens when you don't provide an application Icon. Add a 57x57 png icon to your project and save it's name in the `Project-Info.plist` file for the key `Icon File`.